# I can't make a basic project run with javaexe

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, wrapper

I created a basic program in order to see how to make javaexe run;
The program has to be a windows service and should display a icon on the taskbar, when one click in the menu item, a messageBox is displayed.
But it does not run, especially the icon is not displayed.
Do you know why?

here are my files:

the service:
    package service;

```
/**
* Created by User on 26/10/2014.
*/
public class Exemple_ServiceManagement {

static Corps app=null;

public static boolean serviceInit (){

    app=new Corps();
    return true;
}

public static void serviceFinish (){

    app.setEnd(true);

}

public static String[] serviceGetInfo (){

    return new String[]{"mon exemple","test","pas auto",
    "1"};


}

}
```

the core part:

```
public class Corps extends Thread{

    public boolean isEnd() {
        return isEnd;
    }

    public void setEnd(boolean isEnd) {
        this.isEnd = isEnd;
    }

    public boolean isEnd=false;



    /*******************************************/
    public Corps()
    {
        start();
    }

    /*******************************************/
    public void run(){
        while (!isEnd){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

and the taskbar part:

```
public class Exemple_TaskbarManagement {

    public static void taskInit() {

    }

    public static String[][] taskGetMenu(boolean isRightClick, int menuID) {

        return new String[][]
                {
                        {"1", "test" , "", ""},

                };
    }

    public static void taskDoAction (boolean isRightClick, int menuID){

        if (!isRightClick && menuID==1){

            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Menu cliqué");
        }


    }

    public static String[] taskGetInfo (){

        return new String[]
                {
                        "JavaExe : mon exemple",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "",
                        ""

                };


    }

}
```

finally, the output directory contains:
- the file "Exemple.exe" (the javaexe exe)
- the file "Exemple.jar", generated from the above sources, without manifest
- the file "Exemple.properties", here is it:

```
JREversion      =
PersonalClasspath   =
MainArgs        =
MainClass       =
PersonalOptions     =
RunAsService        = 
RunType         =1
ClassDirectory      =
ResourceDirectory   =
URL_InstallJRE      =
Display_BoxInstall  =
PathBrowser     =
PathJRE         =
```

my question is very simple : do you know what's going wrong?

thanks

olivier

ps : I had a look at the example files but I want to make a basic project, not take an other from somebody else, in order to understand what I do.

Comment: I don't know specifically about Windows services in *Java*, but the basic concept of services is that they are always-running, session independent background processes like Unix daemons. They are not intended to interract *directly* with the UI.

Comment: yes, you're right but javaexe is an API which allows to create 2 programs in one : the program exists in 2 versions in memory : a version as a service, and the other as a tasbkar icon manager; the 2 versions are roughly independant, but there exists ways (particular methods) to exchange informations between them.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: what is your version of JRE (32bits or 64bits) ? and JavaExe ?

Comment: Hello, the JRE is 1.8.0_25 x64 and javaexe is the 3.2 version, with the x32 EXE(not the x64).

Comment: you must use the same version : 32bits for JavaExe and JRE, or 64bits for JavaExe and JRE

Comment: ...and rename your Corps class to Exemple class...or rename Exemple to Corps (and so Exemple_* to Corps_*)